# images.get_serving_url failing for GCS image blobs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blobstore, google-app-engine-python

I have an older (Python 2.7) Google App Engine app that I recently deployed using Google Cloud Platform (gcloud), since appcfg was retired.  I'm having issues using the images.get_serving_url not working for uploaded image blobs.  The Images API is returning 'TransformationError'.  This code worked previously for years in production before the switch to google cloud platform.

One quick thing to note is that Google Cloud Platform created a default storage bucket for blobs.  Previously, I think GAE was using the Blobstore, so even though this change is transparent to developers, probably a lot has happened under the hood.  I think for some reason my app is having issues creating the image url for the file stored on the cloud storage bucket.

I made a very simple test case to replicate the issue.  Are there new requirements, or should this work?

```
class testUpload(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        uploadUrl = blobstore.create_upload_url('/testUploadHandler')
        print("Generated upload url: %s" % uploadUrl)

        self.response.out.write("""
            <html><body>
            <form action="{0}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            </body></html>""".format(uploadUrl))
        

class testUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        
        logging.info("testUploadHandler called.")
        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        blob_key = upload.key()
        image_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
        self.redirect(image_url)
```

The deployed code returns the following error on the web server (local dev server is fine):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~puzzleflow-dev/20210325t013659.433969250928848570/puzzleflow.py", line 4171, in post
    image_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1866, in get_serving_url
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 615, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1970, in get_serving_url_hook
    raise _ToImagesError(e, readable_blob_key)
TransformationError
```

Also, you can try this yourself by going to this link (it should be publicly available):

https://puzzleflow-dev.appspot.com/testUpload

Comment: What's the access control of your bucket? I tested your code and it works fine for me. The only difference is that I used [webapp2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/blobstore/api/main.py) and that my bucket is fine-grained. Also, I wouldn't recommend exposing your service link to public as you may get sudden request spike, which may impact your billing.

Comment: Access control was exactly it, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I see that you recently switched to 'gcloud' because appcfg (from the GUI, GAE Launcher) was retired. I also faced the same issue and because I preferred the GUI to a command line, I created a GUI to replace GAE Launcher. I don't know if I'm allowed to post links to my own site directly in comments but you can find the link to the site in my profile. Feel free to try it out and provide some feedback if you will. Cheers

Comment: I had similar problem, the real reason is the access to cloud storage. It seems google is automatically uploading all the files to google cloud storage instead of  blobstore for new uploads. The GAE role needs write access to google cloud storage. In IAM add Cloud Storage write access to appname@........com principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I had switched my access control to Uniform, since Google says this is the 'recommended' setting.  I'm not well-versed enough on the differences between Fine-Grained and Uniform, but switching it back to Fine-Grained fixed the problem.